# Aurelia binding not update even though first time data looks ok

Tags: javascript, binding, aurelia

I am new to Aurelia and encountered a binding issue. I tried to go through the posts about Aurelia binding, but did not see a particular one that is similar.

It's very likely that it is a newbie mistake, but I got stuck because there is not error / warning reported in chrome developer tools console.

I have a typical list, that is injected with a stub web-api.
    import {WebAPI} from './web-api';
    import {inject} from 'aurelia-framework';

```
@inject(WebAPI)
export class LtvRequestList {
  constructor(api) {
    this.api = api;
    this.selectedId = 'initid';
    //this.ltvRequests = [];
    this.ltvRequests = [  {
    requestId: '11111-a',
    accounts: ["account0", "account1"],
    proposalId: 1257,
    userId: 'user-id-0',
    eventTime: 135511540000
  }];
  }

  searchLtvRequests(keywords, endTime) {
    this.api.getLtvRequests(keywords, endTime)
        .then(
          ltvRequests => this.setLtvRequests(ltvRequests));
  }

  setLtvRequests(requests) {
    // for (var req in requests) {
    //   this.ltvRequests.push(req);
    // }
    console.info("before set, id", this.selectedId);
    this.selectedId='callBackId';
    this.ltvRequests = requests;

    console.info("set ltv requests, id = ", this.selectedId);

    console.info("set ltv requests, length = ", this.ltvRequests.length);

  }
  select(ltvRequest) {
    this.selectedId = ltvRequest.requestId;
    return true;
  }

  get canRequestList() {
      return !this.api.isRequesting;
  }
}
```

I have a html template

```
<template>
  <div class="request-list">
    <span>length: ${ltvRequests.length}, selected: ${selectedId}</span>
    <ul class="list-group">
      <li repeat.for="request of ltvRequests" class="list-group-item ${request.requestId === $parent.selectedId ? 'active' : ''}">
          <h4 class="list-group-item-heading"><span>${$index+1}. accounts: </span><span>${request.accounts[0]}</span></h4>
          <p class="list-group-item-text"><span>eventTime: </span><span>${request.eventTime}</span></p>
          <p class="list-group-item-text"><span>proposalId: </span><span>${request.proposalId}</span></p>
          <p class="list-group-item-text"><span>requestId: </span><span>${request.requestId}</span></p>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>
```

the binding would work initially as you can see that I put in one element for the ltvRequests array, all fields including the length and the id would show in the page. Then in the page I have a button where use click and trigger the searchLtvRequests. I can verify that the callback is good because I output the array length (would become 2) and relevant info in the setLtvRequests callback. However, the html page never updates for the new values...

Again, no error reported in chrome developer tool console, the same issue is in safari.

I wonder whether I made some really newbie mistake...

[EDIT] I quickly uploaded the toy app at [Github here](https://github.com/yougusnc/ltv-trace-app.git). Just a quick note that one needs to put some random words in the keywords input box before the "search" button is enabled.

Comment: Your code seems fine to me... put a debugger in the `setLtvRequests()` and see if it's being set correctly

Comment: Fabio, thanks for looking at it. I did have the consol.info in there an it did out put the "selectedId" before and after the set correctly, I also break there to verify that the array has been updated to 2 elements instead of one... I also tried to turn the console output level to debug, could not extract more info there.

Comment: It's hard to tell what's going on without looking at the specific part of the code... Could you reproduce the error in this gist https://gist.run/?id=c32f322b1f56e6f0a83679512247af7b ?

Comment: Hi, Fabio, sorry that I replied late because we were doing a product launch over the weekend. I haven't done any gist before, so I am not sure how to commit code into your gist. I did created one public gist here that would re-produce the problem. https://gist.run/?id=1ef0463a3e755bce9e5f36d8df5d544d Would you please have a quick look when you get the chance?